# Python Function for List of Lists

Tags: python, list, function

I want to find the lengths of words in sentences, and return the results as a list of lists.

So something like

```
lucky = ['shes up all night til the sun', 'shes up all night for the fun', 'hes up all night to get some', 'hes up all night to get lucky']
```

should become

```
[[4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5]]
```

Here's the code

```
result =[]

def sentancewordlen(x)
    for i in x:
        splitlist = x.split(" ")
        temp=[]
        for y in splitlist:
                l = len(y)
                temp.append(l)
        result.append(temp)
sentancewordlen(lucky)
```

What comes out is the results of the last sentence, with each length in its own list.

```
[[3], [2], [3], [5], [2], [3], [5]]
```

Any idea where I'm goofing up?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you call `x.split` instead of `i.split` in your loop, your code works absolutely fine and gives the right result.

Answer (score 4):

I hate thinking about these changing lists altogether.  The more pythonic version is with list comprehensions:

```
result = [
    [len(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]
    for sentence in sentences]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise solution would be:

```
lengths = [[len(w) for w in s.split()] for s in lucky]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5]]
```

Explanation:

`for s in lucky` will iterate through all strings in lucky. With `s.split()` we then split each string `s` into the words it is made up of. Using `len(w)`, we then obtain the length (number of characters) for each word `w` in `s.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

[The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608501/python-function-for-list-of-lists/42608844#comment72346651_42608501) in your question gives you the reason why your code is failing. Here is another solution leveraging the use of [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

Python 3, you get `map` objects that you will have to call `list` on if you want to see the output as you expect.

```
>>> res = [list(map(len, x.split())) for x in lucky]
>>> res
[[4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5]]
```

Python 2 will give you a list from calling `map`:

```
>>> res = [map(len, x.split()) for x in lucky]
>>> res
[[4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5]]
```